# How to find the limit of function $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {a^b-b^a} {a-b}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ be continuous functions such that $a(0)=b(0)=3$

How to find the limit: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {a^b-b^a} {a-b}$$

I tried to annihilate $b-a$ by writing $a^b-b^a= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {{(b\ln a)}^k-({a\ln b)}^k} {k!}$ but it leads to another limit $\lim \frac {b\ln a-a\ln b} {a-b}$ that seems to be similar to the first one...

Comment: If you're not going to write $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ in the limit, then you should suppress $x\to$.

Comment: yeah, I just want to make it clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, if $\lim_{x\to0}a(x) = \lim_{x\to0}b(x) = y$, then for any function $f$ differentiable at $y$ you have
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(a(x))-f(b(x))}{a(x)-b(x)} = f'(y).$$

Now, on your case you have
$$\frac{a^b-b^a}{a-b}=-\frac{a^a-a^b}{a-b}+\frac{a^a-b^b}{a-b}-\frac{b^a-b^b}{a-b}.$$

I think you can conclude from there on ;)

Comment: And if $\;a,b\;$ aren't differentiable?

Comment: Can you explain it rigorously? I don't see how to the limit tends to the derivative.

Comment: The thing is, $a$ and $b$ don't have to be differentiable, only $f$ has to be. They just have not to be both locally constant around 0, but without that hypothesis neither the derivate property nor the original question statements make sense.

Comment: For a rigorous proof, just write $a(x) = y + a_0(x)$, $b(x) = y + b_0(x)$, and use first order limited development of $f$ at $y$.